# Numpy-y way to build a polynomial array from set of points

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I'm working on Polynomial Transform for a homework assignment. I'm using a document from vanderbilt.edu as my starting point. [Polynomial Transform](http://eecs.vanderbilt.edu/courses/cs359/other_links/notes/nonrigid/Polynomial%20Transformation.doc)

I have a set of points:

```
square_points = (
    # x, y
    (37, 44 ),  # x1,y1
    (67, 74 ),  # x2,y2
    (97,104 ),  # x3,y3
    (247,194),  # x4,y4
    (157, 97),  # x5,y5
)
```

that I'd like to turn into a Numpy array, rows as the polynomials:

```
[[1, x1, y1, x1*y1],
 [1, x2, y2, x2*y2],
 [1, x3, y3, x3*y3],
 [1, x4, y4, x4*y4],
 [1, x5, y5, x5*y5]]
```

I'm still learning Numpy. I'd like to learn a clean way to build such an array from my list of points. (As opposed to building the array from hardcoded square_points[0][1], etc.)

So far I have:

```
P = np.ones((5,5))
P[:,1] = [ n[0] for n in square_points ]
P[:,2] = [ n[1] for n in square_points ]
P[:,3] = [ n[0]*n[1] for n in square_points ]
```

which seems a bit cumbersome. Is there a cleaner, more Numpy-y way to create such an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! Just do what you're already doing, but leave out the list comprehension...

E.g.

```
import numpy as np
square_points = np.array([
    [37,  44],  # x1,y1
    [67,  74],  # x2,y2
    [97,  104], # x3,y3
    [247, 194], # x4,y4
    [157, 97],  # x5,y5
    ])
x, y = square_points.T

P = np.ones((5,4))
P[:,1] = x
P[:,2] = y
P[:,3] = x * y
```

Or if you'd prefer, you can even do it in one line:

```
P[:,1:] = np.array([x, y, x*y]).T
```

Comment: Can you think of a nice way to handle the (well, 'a') generalization to all the powers of the coords, in the sense that the columns here are x0**0*x1**0, x0**1*x1**0, etc.?  I can do it semi-brute-force but it feels like there should be a purely numpy-based one-liner.

Comment: Brilliant! Numpy continues to amaze me. Thx for more great numpy help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at a more generic polynomial expansion kernel, such as the one found in the [MDP toolkit](http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/api/mdp.nodes.PolynomialExpansionNode-class.html)